# generic type XMLexception in catel

Tags: catel

I try to use the properties CATEL who generic type.
And I have XmlException in Model attribute.

```
[Serializable]
public class TDS : SavableModelBase<TDS>
{
     public TestType<bool> Tds
     {
          get { return GetValue<TestType<bool>>(TdsProperty); }
          set { SetValue(TdsProperty, value); }
     }
     public static readonly PropertyData TdsProperty = RegisterProperty("Tds", typeof(TestType<bool>));


    public TDS(TestType<bool> tds)
    {
        Tds = tds;
    }
}
```

ViewModel when i use catel prop

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [Model]
    public TDS Xxx      //when assigning XMLException  The '`' character, hexadecimal value 0x60, cannot be included in a name.
    {
        get { return GetValue<TDS>(XxxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XxxProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData XxxProperty = RegisterProperty("Xxx", typeof(TDS));
}
```

class modelBase in main struct, where catel prop

```
[Serializable]
public class TestType<T> : ModelBase
{
    public TestType(ushort val)
    {
        Val = val;
    }

    public ushort Val
    {
        get { return GetValue<ushort>(ValProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData ValProperty = RegisterProperty("Val", typeof(ushort));

}
```

I think that the problem, in a generic catel prop

Help me!!!

Comment: What version are you using? If you think you found a bug, please report it here https://catelproject.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: <package id="Catel.Core" version="3.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Catel.Extensions.Controls" version="3.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Catel.MVVM" version="3.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: I think this is a not bug. please collect a similar application and perform the test. it is important to have a attribute [Model].

Comment: First answer is always: upgrade to the latest version

Comment: I update catel to the 4.0 version. but the problem remains

Comment: Geert van Horrik, problem is actual. If i remove generic,  it will make a bad model.

Comment: Please create issue at http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker/, but we are very busy, so can't promise a fix date.